Nginx ingress controller serves fake kubernetes certificate despite TLS being configured for domain
I keep getting the "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate" when accessing services through HTTPS and the nginx ingress controller.
Initially I used [keyvault-acmebot][1] to generate a LetsEncrypt certificate, and then [external-secrets][2] to save the certificate as a Secret of type kubernetes.io/tls. This worked and the Secret was generated with both tls.crt and tls.key data properties.
As the wrong certificate was served, googling around led me to try [cert-manager][3] instead. Thought that acmebot might have misconfigured the certificate and key inside the secret somehow. Unfortunately, I get the same issue with a Certificate/Secret generated by cert-manager, minimizing the possibility that the issue is related to invalid data in the tls.key and tls.crt data properties of the tls secret.
Nginx is deployed into the same namespace as the Ingress resource, the TLS secrets and the pods that requests are forwarded to.
When the Ingress resource only contains 1 host in the rules and tls sections, Nginx throws an error getting the SSL certificate, as shown below.
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-66b9474989-4b666 I0423 13:25:57.447031       6 main.go:107] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="wordpress/wordpress-ingress"
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-66b9474989-4b666 W0423 13:25:57.780583       6 controller.go:1707] Error getting SSL certificate "portal/portal46-tls": local SSL certificate portal/portal46-tls was not found
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-66b9474989-4b666 W0423 13:25:57.780624       6 controller.go:1436] Error getting SSL certificate "portal/portal46-tls": local SSL certificate portal/portal46-tls was not found. Using default certificate
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-66b9474989-4b666 I0423 13:25:57.807106       6 main.go:107] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="portal/portal-ingress"
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-66b9474989-4b666 W0423 13:25:57.815882       6 controller.go:1707] Error getting SSL certificate "portal/portal46-tls": local SSL certificate portal/portal46-tls was not found
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-66b9474989-4b666 W0423 13:25:57.815916       6 controller.go:1436] Error getting SSL certificate "portal/portal46-tls": local SSL certificate portal/portal46-tls was not found. Using default certificate
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-66b9474989-4b666 I0423 13:25:57.854328       6 main.go:107] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="portal/portal-ingress"
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-66b9474989-4b666 I0423 13:25:57.861715       6 backend_ssl.go:67] "Adding secret to local store" name="portal/portal46-tls"

Ingress resource 1 host

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portal-ingress
  namespace: portal
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - portal46.mydomain.dk
    secretName: portal46-tls
  rules:
  - host: portal46.mydomain.dk
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: portal-46-service
            port:
              number: 80

The acmebot certificate was generated for: portal.mydomain.dk
The cert-manager certificate was generated for: portal46.mydomain.dk
I tried adding two hosts to the Ingress resource, and it looks like Nginx is able to read the certificates, but defaults to the fake certificate. There is only one certificate/secret available and it only works for one of the hosts. So it seems that it can actually read the contents of the certificate:
Ingress with 2 hosts:
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portal-ingress
  namespace: portal
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - portal.mydomain.dk
    - portal46.mydomain.dk
    secretName: portal46-tls
  rules:
  - host: portal.mydomain.dk
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: portal-46-service
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: portal46.mydomain.dk
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: portal-46-service
            port:
              number: 80

Error message
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:09:34.499546       7 controller.go:1457] Using default certificate
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b I0423 15:09:34.525738       7 main.go:107] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="portal/portal-ingress"
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:09:34.532739       7 controller.go:1450] Unexpected error validating SSL certificate "portal/portal46-tls" for server "portal.mydomain.dk": x509: certificate is valid for portal46.mydomain.dk, not portal.mydomain.dk
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:09:34.532917       7 controller.go:1451] Validating certificate against DNS names. This will be deprecated in a future version
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:09:34.532947       7 controller.go:1456] SSL certificate "portal/portal46-tls" does not contain a Common Name or Subject Alternative Name for server "portal.mydomain.dk": x509: certificate is valid for portal46.mydomain.dk, not portal.mydomain.dk
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:09:34.532964       7 controller.go:1457] Using default certificate
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b I0423 15:09:34.533041       7 controller.go:190] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b I0423 15:09:34.532828       7 event.go:364] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"portal", Name:"portal-ingress", UID:"14aeeb46-f8b9-45b4-9470-06afa193c174", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"9598466", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b I0423 15:09:34.584278       7 controller.go:210] "Backend successfully reloaded"
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b I0423 15:09:34.585164       7 event.go:364] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"portal", Name:"nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b", UID:"1191b811-7784-4c7a-87a1-1d1044136ace", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"9587742", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:10:16.157891       7 controller.go:1450] Unexpected error validating SSL certificate "portal/portal46-tls" for server "portal.mydomain.dk": x509: certificate is valid for portal46.mydomain.dk, not portal.mydomain.dk
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:10:16.157935       7 controller.go:1451] Validating certificate against DNS names. This will be deprecated in a future version
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:10:16.157953       7 controller.go:1456] SSL certificate "portal/portal46-tls" does not contain a Common Name or Subject Alternative Name for server "portal.mydomain.dk": x509: certificate is valid for portal46.mydomain.dk, not portal.mydomain.dk
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b W0423 15:10:16.157967       7 controller.go:1457] Using default certificate
nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b I0423 15:10:16.185627       7 main.go:107] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="portal/portal-ingress"


Nginx is deployed as a HelmRelease. Here is the deployed YAML.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-04-23T14:33:43Z"
  generateName: nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx-ingress-portal
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.10.0
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.10.0
    pod-template-hash: 846454677b
  name: nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b-7mr7b
  namespace: portal
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-846454677b
    uid: 87535fba-5cea-495a-aaa2-394533e30c47
  resourceVersion: "9587806"
  uid: 1191b811-7784-4c7a-87a1-1d1044136ace
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - /nginx-ingress-controller
    - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller
    - --election-id=nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-leader
    - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
    - --ingress-class=nginx
    - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller
    - --validating-webhook=:8443
    - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
    - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
    - --enable-metrics=false
    env:
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: LD_PRELOAD
      value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
    image: registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.10.0@sha256:42b3f0e5d0846876b1791cd3afeb5f1cbbe4259d6f35651dcc1b5c980925379c
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command:
          - /wait-shutdown
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 5
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 10254
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: controller
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 443
      name: https
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 8443
      name: webhook
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 10254
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 90Mi
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      capabilities:
        add:
        - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        drop:
        - ALL
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      runAsNonRoot: true
      runAsUser: 101
      seccompProfile:
        type: RuntimeDefault
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
      name: webhook-cert
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-bkwcl
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: aks-apppool-96597981-vmss000000
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx
  serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure
    operator: Exists
  volumes:
  - name: webhook-cert
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-admission
  - name: kube-api-access-bkwcl
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-23T14:33:45Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodReadyToStartContainers
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-23T14:33:43Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-23T14:33:54Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-23T14:33:54Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-23T14:33:43Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: containerd://d9a112d67fcd8712f10cbd66b28494622522682a1d8079082c76b6696f0bec7f
    image: sha256:ffcc66479b5baa5a65f94b8b7c73c6ee5ed989ec0b7f8f9371999f335ce4f44c
    imageID: registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller@sha256:42b3f0e5d0846876b1791cd3afeb5f1cbbe4259d6f35651dcc1b5c980925379c
    lastState: {}
    name: controller
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2024-04-23T14:33:44Z"
  hostIP: 10.0.1.199
  hostIPs:
  - ip: 10.0.1.199
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.0.1.203
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.0.1.203
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2024-04-23T14:33:43Z"


It is also worth mentioning, that I have another Ingress resource in another namespace, which this nginx controller is also taking care of. That Service does not need HTTPS, which I why I placed the Nginx controller in the "portal" namespace, where the service needs HTTPs, so that Nginx can read the Secrets.
What am I doing wrong here ?
UPDATE 1
The above happens when I try to access the service through its public load balancer in Azure. I use the public IP and change the host with curl like this:
curl http://x.x.x.x/ -H "host: portal.mydomain.dk" -kv
When accessing the service through the ingress controller from another pod in the cluster, following error is output:
root@wordpress-656f9c5ff8-p2x4q:/var/www/html# curl https://nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-admission.portal.svc.cluster.local -kv
*   Trying 10.0.2.69:443...
* Connected to nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-admission.portal.svc.cluster.local (10.0.2.69) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=nil2
*  start date: Apr 23 14:20:04 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 30 14:20:04 2124 GMT
*  issuer: O=nil1
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* using HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-admission.portal.svc.cluster.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2024 16:54:20 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host nginx-ingress-portal-ingress-nginx-controller-admission.portal.svc.cluster.local left intact



  [1]: https://github.com/shibayan/keyvault-acmebot
  [2]: https://external-secrets.io/latest/
  [3]: https://cert-manager.io/


Your TLS certificate must be issued to the Host of the HTTP client; which you mentioned in your curl command. Try to get your Secret's TLS cert with the following command and verify its content: k get secret/portal46-tls -n portal -o jsonpath='{.data.tls\.crt}' | base64 -d | step certificate inspect -. If the Subject or any of the alternative names match your Host, the first check passes and there might be possible other locations to look for.
